# rsync failing but only from within bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a simple two line bash script that copies a csv file (list of users from a webapp) to a remote server.

```
#! /bin/bash 

/home/james/bin/UserList.py >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog & date >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog 
rsync /home/james/data/TMTUsers.csv myserver.com:~/data/TMTtest.csv >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog 2>> /home/james/logs/TMTerrlog
```

The first just calls a python script that generate the csv file, stores it in /home/james/data/TMTUsers.csv and outputs some data that I store in a log file. The second line rsyncs that file to the remote server (ssh is set up to use passwordless authentication)

Now here is the bizarre thing. When I run this script, either interactively from the command line, or as a cron job, the python script works fine and generates the correct file but rsync only transfers about 10-15% of the file (approx 100kb of an 800kb file) and it seems to stop at a different point each time. There is no error output (which as you can see I redirect to a log file). But when I run the exact same rsync command from the command line, it works perfectly (the whole file is transferred). I tried using rcp instead of rsync and the same thing happens.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on the local server and 14.04 on the remote server.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `&` in this line:

```
/home/james/bin/UserList.py >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog & date >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog
```

that `&` tells the shell to run `UserList.py` in the background, and continue without waiting for it to finish. This actually has a couple of bad effects: for one thing, both `UserList.py` and `date` are trying to append to the log simultaneously, and more importantly the `rsync` is running before `UserList.py` has a chance to finish creating the csv file. That's why it's not all getting transferred -- it doesn't all exist when the transfer happens.

The fix is easy, just lose the `&` and run each command separately, in a predictable sequence (note that I assume the date should be first in the log):

```
#! /bin/bash 

date >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog 
/home/james/bin/UserList.py >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog
rsync /home/james/data/TMTUsers.csv myserver.com:~/data/TMTtest.csv >> /home/james/logs/TMTUserExportLog 2>> /home/james/logs/TMTerrlog
```